# Wake on LAN on Asus motherboard

Tags: motherboard, bios, wake-on-lan

Trying to enable `Wake on LAN` on my 5 years old Asus motherboard with integrated NIC. Trying to find and enable this feature in bios, but can't find where it is.

I was expecting to find it under Advanced->APM, but there is no such thing:

[image]

How to enable WOL in Asus bios?

Motherboard model : Asus B85M-E

UPD

I have configured following settings in Windows:

[image]

[image]
[image]
And I'm using [wakemeonlan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html) software

[image]

Comment: Look for a BIOS upgrade?

Comment: You didn’t specify the model of your motherboard. How will anybody be able to help you?

Comment: Motherboard model : Asus B85M-E

Comment: I believe what @C. Wong is trying to say is that WOL might be already enabled. Have you enabled the feature from the properties of your network adapter (If running Windows)? If yes, how are you sending the magic packet?

Comment: I have updated my question body with more details

Comment: And the `Wake on Magic Packet` option is enabled?

Answer (score 6):

According to the manual for that mainboard the feature is called `Power On By PCIE/PCI`

> Power On By PCIE/PCI
>   [Disabled]  Disables the PCIE/PCI> devices to
>   generate a wake‑on‑LAN feature of the  Intel ® /Realtek LAN device.
>
> [Enabled]  Enables the PCIE/PCI devices to generate a wake‑on‑LAN
>   feature of the  Intel ® /Realtek LAN device.

SOURCE:
https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/B85M-E/E9915_B85M-E_Manual_v3_web.pdf

NOTE: The settings in Windows have no effect on being able to wake the PC from a power off state.

Comment: What do you mean that "The settings in Windows have no effect on being able to wake the PC from a power off state."? That's what we want to achieve.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can enable it in the driver settings in Windows but it won't work unless it is also enabled in the BIOS. If the machine is powered off the driver settings are meaningless. The only thing that setting allows you to do is wake from a sleep state. If you want to be able to wake from full power off and sleep state you need to set wake on LAN in both the BIOS and in the driver settings.

Comment: On Asus AM1I-A mobo I had to also enable option "Realtek PXE OPROM" somewhere in the "Advanced" menu.